# Ubuntu 13.10 64bit installation problems with hp elitebook 8540w

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, software-installation

I have tried both 32bit and 64bit versions of ubuntu 13.10 and 12.04 LTS and allways the same screen pops on! And I tried it with CD and USB.
For burning CD I used Poweriso.
For USB i used poweriso and Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.1.

This is the screen that pops up when trying to install - [image: Screen photo]

I'm using HP EliteBook 8540w
intel core 2 i5-520M 
Nvidia quadro fx 1800M
Currently using windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Ubuntu version and/or 32bit or 64bit issue but caused by how Nvidia hardware (NVIDIA Quadro FX 1800M - 343.22) in the HP Elitebook 8540w is handled by Ubuntu during Live CD or plain install. I would call it a bug but it is there for quite some time. It can be fixed though. There is another site mentioned on this thread but it is a bit too complex since it proposes to edit Grub, which isn't necessary and tricky since Grub2.

Further I found that downloading the driver .run file from the official Nvidia site certainly was NOT the right driver and caused problems, whereas the standard (-current or -340) as available through the Ubuntu repositories was fine.

Here is the straightforward procedure (I tried distro Zorin 9, recommended for WindowsMovers, but assume Ubuntu 14 is the same)

1. Load a Zorin9 (Ubuntu14) LiveDVD into the DVD reader or connect a Live USB
   stick and (re-)boot from it
2. Pess `any key` when you see the first screen with the `* / keyboard`
3. Pess `F6` and then `ESC` - allowing you to edit the boot
   command with the `Arrow keys` and typing in or over the existing command
4. Navigate to `quiet splash` and replace that with  `nouveau.modeset=0`
5. Continue boot with `F10`.
6. In live CD you will be using the Xorg 1024x768 driver and you cannot update the driver in live CD mode. So wait until CD booting is ready (no strange distorted screen now!)
7. From there install on HD. Dont forget to have an internet connection or install will hang
8. Reboot (from the HD)
9. At the boot screen (Zorin or Ubuntu) press `E` and again here replace `quiet splash` with  `nouveau.modeset=0` and boot with `F10`

(off topic) (In case (as mine) your password is not accepted even when you are sure it is correct, you need to reboot in Advanced-recovery-root mount as rw (see below for the command) and check if there is a home directory, or change the access rights, since that didnt happen well in Zorin...)

10. Update your driver by Software Center/Dash, or in terminal mode as below, which for the 8540w means looking for nvidia-340 or nvidia-current.
11. Reboot. You should see the Nvidia logo shortly and you know you are fine!

Alternative commandline from point 8:

8. Reboot
9. Select `Advanced` and then `recovery`
10. Select `networking` (have a wired internet connection!) and then `root`
11. `sudo mount -o rw,remount /`
12. `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`
13. Look at which driver will be recommended. you can then
14. - `sudo apt-get update`
      and then
    - `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340`
    - or `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`
15. Reboot

You should be fine now.

In terms of usability I find the HP8540 OK with Ubuntu but it seems to me the power/heat/fan control is not at the Windows driver level. Nevertheless, still a great laptop especially if free.